# sudo apt-get update does not connect to 10.10.5.18

Tags: apt, update

I am having this prob since morning only and before that everything was normal. I can connect to my Pi through ssh using putty on my windows 7. The problem is when I run `sudo apt-get update`, it gets stuck as shown in the image below. For once I just gave keyboard interrupt (`ctrl + C`) and re-run to update and let it as it is, first it shows the same thing as shown above and after a long time it shows as shown in the image and gets stuck forever.

[image]

My internet connection is working fine, i can ping google.com, gmail.com, even yahoo.com, but when I try to ping `10.10.5.18` it does not connect.

I have searched this forum and googled everything possible. I understand about `apt-get update`, but nothing has helped me so far.

Please let me know if anybody understands why this is happening and how can I solve this problem.

Comment: 10.10.x.x are intranet addresses (it is not an internet address). Why are you trying to talk to it?  Is it a proxy?

Comment: Actually every time i do apt-get update it tries to connect 10.10.5.18 as shown in the image. And I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Have a look in /etc/apt/sources.list for the repository address and try pinging by that address by name.

Comment: This is what I have in sources.list file

`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
#Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
#deb http://raspbian.mirrors.wvstateu.edu/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi `

And I can ping the mirrordirector.raspbian.org.

Comment: I guess I found the solution. Thanks for point it out joan.. 
It was my proxy issue, which was the problem. Quiet long back I had set proxy for making it work in my office. I just removed the proxy and voila! its getting updated like smooth..
Thanks Joan Once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found the solution. Thanks for point it out joan.. It was my proxy issue, which was the problem.

Quiet long back I had set proxy for making it work in my office. I just removed the proxy and voila! its getting updated like smooth.. Thanks Joan Once again.

Comment: Please make this as solved.